# How can I recursively search for multiple patterns on linux?

Tags: linux, string, shell, search, command-line

I am trying to find files that include either of the following two patterns:

```
select AND into
SELECT AND INTO
select AND INTO
SELECT AND into
```

By AND, I mean a logical *and*. I am using the following command:

```
grep -r 'INTO\|SELECT' .
```

to check if a file has INTO *and* SELECT, but this returns the string if either one exists, but I need both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the patterns have to occur on the same line, you can use

```
grep -r '\(INTO.*SELECT\)\|\(SELECT.*INTO\)' .
```

The two alternatives are to cover either order.  If the two patterns can occur on separate lines, try this:

```
grep -r -Z -l 'INTO' . | xargs -0 grep 'SELECT'
```

The first grep will print the names (`-l`) of the files that have `INTO`.  `-Z` and `xargs -0` work together to pass those names to a second grep, which looks for `SELECT`.

**Note** thanks to @ghoti: for grep versions other than GNU, try `--null` instead of `-Z`.

Comment: Is there to ignore cases (as in search for Select or sElEct)

Comment: @hadis The `-i` option makes it case-insensitive.

Comment: @hadis - `man grep` from your shell will give you lots of cool tips.

Comment: @cxw: grep's `-Z` option causes it to behave like `zgrep`, which will search compressed data (or decompress before search if you prefer). Perhaps you mean `--null`?  Note that this option may only exist in GNU grep. While that's probably fine for this question (as it's tagged [tag:linux]), it should be noted that it's not portable.

Comment: @ghoti thanks - edited.  GNU grep 2.24 has both `-Z` and `--null`, so I went with the shorter one :)